# Exclude loop from progressive cost algorithm

Tags: c#, formula, pow

I have an algorithm to calculate the amount of products on target cost. The cost of one product is not constant, it is more expensive by 10%. The target cost may be exceeded if it is closer than the incomplete cost.

I need to optimize code and exclude loop, because it is not effective at high 
target cost.

This is my working solution with unit test (nunit framework)

```
public static int CalculateProductAmountOnCost( double targetCost, double productRate )
{
    if ( targetCost <= 0 || productRate <= 0 )
        return 1;

    var previousCollectedCost = 0.0;
    var collectedCost = 0.0;
    var amount = 0;

    for ( ; collectedCost < targetCost; amount++ )
    {
        previousCollectedCost = collectedCost;
        collectedCost += productRate*Math.Pow( 1.1, amount );
    }

    if ( targetCost - previousCollectedCost < collectedCost - targetCost )
        amount -= 1;
    return Math.Max( 1, amount );
}

[Test]
[TestCase( 9, 2, 4 )]
[TestCase( 7, 2, 3 )]
[TestCase( 0, 2, 1 )]
[TestCase( 9, 0, 1 )]
[TestCase( 4.5, 0.2, 12 )]
public void TradeDealHelper_CalculateProductAmountOnGemCostTest( double targetCost, double productRate,
        int expectedAmount )
{
    var actualAmount = TradeDealHelper.CalculateProductAmountOnCost( targetCost, productRate );

    Assert.AreEqual( expectedAmount, actualAmount );
}
```

Comment: So, you're asking for someone to tell you how your code performance?

Comment: @JuanFerrer I'm asking for help in writing this algorithm without a loop, I tried a few options, but they do not pass the tests

Comment: I was working on an answer, but I only managed to shave off about 0.07 seconds after testing with 500k calls. Can't think of a better way of doing it, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static int CalculateProductAmountOnCost2(double targetCost, double productRate)
{
    if (targetCost <= 0 || productRate <= 0)
        return 1;

    var amount = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log(((targetCost / (productRate * 10)) + 1), 1.1) - 1);

    var lowerCost = productRate * 10 * (Math.Pow(1.1, amount + 1) - 1);
    var upperCost = productRate * 10 * (Math.Pow(1.1, amount + 2) - 1);

    if (targetCost - lowerCost > upperCost - targetCost)
        amount++;

    return Math.Max(1, amount + 1);
}
```

There is a bit of math you can use. What follows is basically mathematical stuff, not code.

Your total cost is:

```
totalCost = productRate + productRate * 1.1 + productRate * (1.1 ^ 2) + ... + productRate * (1.1 ^ n)
```

Which can be rewritten as:

```
totalCost = productRate * (1 + 1.1 + 1.1 ^ 2 + ... 1.1 ^ n)
```

There is a formula to calculate that sum:

```
1 + a + a ^ 2 + ... a ^ n = (a ^ (n + 1) - 1) / (a - 1)
```

So your total cost is now:

```
totalCost = productRate * ((1.1 ^ (n + 1) - 1) / (1.1 - 1))

totalCost = productRate * 10 * (1.1 ^ (n + 1) - 1)
```

We apply this last formula to find `n` for your `targetCost`, and we get:

```
n = Math.Log((targetCost / (productRate * 10)) + 1, 1.1) - 1
```

(that's logarithm in base 1.1)

The code is applying these formulas.